# how to run two commands simultaneously in shell script?

Tags: shell, sass, jekyll

I am trying to make a shell script run `jeykll -w serve` and `sass --watch style.scss:style.css` so I don't have to worry each time I want to develop locally. So I made a shell script, but obviously, if I put the jekyll command first, it won't run the sass one till jekyll is done. So how can run two commands at once? Do I have to make a command to open another tab in the terminal and then run sass? there must be a better way of doing that.

Comment: From a single script, you could run them in the background, ending them in ampersand `&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking to fork the process so the current shell is not waiting on the command I assume.

```
jeykll -w serve && sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

The above will wait for the first command to complete with an non-errored status

```
jeykll -w serve ; sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

The above will wait for the first command to complete and disregard the exit status.

So if I understand correctly you want multiple commands to run near simultaneously. For this you use the & operator at the end of a command reference.

The Bash & (ampersand) is a builtin control operator used to fork processes. From the Bash man page, "If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell".

```
jeykll -w serve &
sass --watch style.scss:style.css &
```