# Stuck with && command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run two commands at same time in terminal but seems the second is not starting at the same time as first one.

I would like to see 'python' line and 'samtools' running in parallel.

```
python -m HTSeq.scripts.count -m intersection-nonempty -f sam -a 20 -t mRNA -i Parent -s yes plate.sam $GFF | awk 'n>=5 { print a[n%5] } { a[n++%5]=$0 }' > plate_F.counts &&

samtools view -h -o exvivo.sam V_S1_L001_aln-pe.bam
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118224/how-to-make-asynchronous-function-calls-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Yes, use `&` instead.

Comment: Get rid of one of the `&` and you will be happy ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run two commands simultaneously in shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470829/how-to-run-two-commands-simultaneously-in-shell-script)

Comment: @unwind That question assumes you want to use `&&`; the OP doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` is a logical `and` operator in `Bash`, heavily used in a construct like `command_a && command_b` which is just a shortcut for "run the first command, and upon success return code run the second command".

In your case, most probably, the first command `python -m ...` exits with a non-zero code, which prevents the second command from running.

If you need the second command to run unconditionally but for whatever reason want them on the same line you can use `command_a; command_b`. Or more strictly, `command_a || true; command_b`.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is executing a command only if the command before finishes with return 0. A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470829/how-to-run-two-commands-simultaneously-in-shell-script) might can get more clearness